# I'm using the PG search gem, with RoR, and search between several tables (multisearchable) the search makes a loop and repeats the results

Tags: search, pg-search

I already checked the models and they are correct, the controller's search method works well.

I tried adding a Uniq in the controller and in the views but it didn't change anything. I don't know if it will be the each with which you do the search?